# How to display exact copy of current ViewController when a button in current ViewController is clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to display another `ViewController` which must be copy of current `ViewController` with same UI(empty new tab like in Safari) when a button is clicked in current `ViewController`. For clear understanding, when we click <kbd>+</kbd> button iOS Safari then new tab in Safari is opened. I want to include this feature in my project.

Comment: And you tried? And the problem you see is? An exact copy of the current view controller isn't the same as a new empty tab...

Comment: @Wain I have created a simple web browser for iPhone and i was unable to find tutorial regarding this problem. Thanks for the edits!

Comment: How is your VC created? Storyboard, xib, code?

Comment: @CalinChitu Storyboard!

Comment: Give it an identifier, then you can create multiple of them using self.storyboard instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a copy loaded is not like a new tab. You're looking to create a new instance of the same view controller. So, just instantiate it again with a new instance variable.